# Angularjs merge json responses as one

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to merge the 3 json reponses $scope.auditorium, $scope.hotels and $scope.exhibitions together as one, is that possible? Help would be very much appreciated ! Or even better, if I'd be able to create a search function which is able to search through all 3 and display the searched result

Code :

```
      myApp.controller('displayCatController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){

              //Display auditoriums information
              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url:'url'
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.auditoriums = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.auditoriums.splice(0,1);
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });


              //Display exhibitions information
              $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                  url: 'url'
                        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                            $scope.exhibitions = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.exhibitions.splice(0,1);
                        }, function errorCallback(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        });



              //Display hotels information
              $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: ''
                  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.hotels = response.data.SrchResults;
                    $scope.hotels.splice(0,1);
                  }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  });

      }]);
```

[image: Exhibition]

Comment: Can you provide the sample values for `$scope.auditorium, $scope.hotels and $scope.exhibitions`, and the expected output?

Comment: @choz added. I am trying to merge them together so that I can have a search function later on to search through them all

Answer (score 1):

You can use Promise.all([...promiseObject])
Example:

```
Promise.all([
      $http(...),
      $http(...),
]).then(function(data) {
     // data is merge array of response 1 and response 2
})
```

Comment: Alright, i'll go research on it and see if it works out. Thanks!

Comment: I am getting undefined value

Comment: Sounds like you might have done `Promise.all([$http(...).then(...), $http(...).then(...)]).then(function(data) {...})`. Remove the individual `then`s, and do all the logic in the final `then`, like this: `Promise.all([$http(...), $http(...)]).then(function(response) {$scope.auditoriums = response[0].data.SrchResults; ... })`